# Please disable Enter to submit comments

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

The quick-submit of comments through the Enter key is a real nuisance on this site. When inputting Japanese through an IME you are required to use Enter, which also submits the comment. Having to remember to hold Shift every time is annoying and may even interfere with some IME's input (possibly, I don't know).

Also see [Pressing Enter in comment box unexpectedly submits form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63644/pressing-enter-in-comment-box-unexpectedly-submits-form/).

Comment: This needs to be changed. Even if there was some other key stroke combination (like Shift+Enter) that might work, typing is so automatic that in all likelihood I'm going to continually forget to do that. Given that there is an "Add Comment" button right there which is immediately accessible by hitting "tab", the enter-to-submit system is an unneccessary and confusing "feature" for those of us using IME. (I use ibus/Anthy on Ubuntu, by the way.)

Comment: In Windows 7, while enter is used for the IME, I am able to use it successfully without it submitting the comment without doing anything special.

Comment: @rebecca - how are you able to get it to not post the comment? as I am also on windows 7 and have had this problem so many times today i've resorted to writing in romaji.

Comment: @MarkHosang, can you give me some exact key stroke steps to attempt to repro?  I just used the IME like I normally do and didn't encounter a problem.

Comment: I just tried some tests, and it appears to happen in comments after you have surpassed the minimum charter count.  these were my key strokes split by space {k a n j i <space> <enter>} and {t e s u t o <enter>}  both resulted in an immediate post.

Comment: Oh yes please. This has been annoying the hell out of me.

Comment: I was thinking of posting this yesterday. This definitely needs to be fixed.

Comment: Ctrl-J Ctrl-J Ctrl-J... I've been thinking of whipping out my Japanese keyboard just so I can press only one button to submit instead of this annoying combination...

Comment: @MarkHosang: in this comment I have 感じ　and てすと and with no auto-posts from using enter in the IME, I'm still typing, and now I'll hit enter to submit the post...

Comment: 漢字　テスト　テスト　テスト　テスト

Comment: yep it auto submitted for me

Comment: テスト　テスト　テスト　テスト

Comment: happend on microsoft ime on a windows 7 machine as well as anthy with ubuntu, both with firefox 4

Comment: Can repro in Firefox.  Chrome handles things properly.  /blame Firefox.

Comment: @Rebecca Does not work using Kotoeri on OS X in anything as far as I've seen. So, it seems to *exclusively* work in IE on Windows so far?

Comment: @deceze, works in Chrome, neither IE nor Firefox.

Comment: bug submitted to firefox bugzilla 

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=661417

Comment: @MarkHosang, the site is in private beta.  Only people who committed will be able to access the site.  Anyone seeing your bug report won't be able to.

Comment: @rebecca - added a note to the bug saying that this also occurs on stackoverflow

Comment: @Rebecca Since I don't think blaming all browser vendors will really work, what's the Stack teams opinion on fixing this? At least a user selectable preference, perhaps?

Comment: Have people been saying this works in Chrome?  I still have Chrome and still have this problem.

Comment: Repro in Firefox 4.0.1 and IE 9.0.8112.16421, not repro in Chrome 11.0.696.71, all on Windows 7 English version with Microsoft Office IME 2010 (for Japanese).

Comment: has anyone tested safari or IE?

Comment: No go in Safari, Chrome or Firefox using Kotoeri on OS X.

Comment: In OS X Safari, a clunky workaround is to select the kanji you want, and then option-space (or whatever your shortcut is) to change your input to something else.  When you do, it'll accept whatever you had specified in Japanese without using the enter key.  Of course, this will be really annoying if you're writing more than a word or two in kanji.

Comment: Hmm... 無視ですか？ Is this issue going to be ignored? :)

Comment: Definitely happening in Firefox. +1!!

Comment: @deceze If you edit your answer about IME's on the meta thread you linked above, it'll bump it to the front page and might grab attention to it.  I've been thinking about adding a bounty on it, but the original meta question itself doesn't discuss the IME angle.

Comment: Kind of surprised by those on OS X who are saying this isn't a problem. I've been struck by it several times already, using OS X 10.6 with a WebKit browser (OmniWeb), using the Return key (On the Mac, "Enter" is only used for the lower-rightmost key on the ten-key keypad). SE needs to not do this. (And if you could somehow remove this annoyance from Facebook as well, it would be appreciated.)

Comment: @Garrett Actually, we are saying it's a problem on OS X too.  @deceze Maybe this should be retagged as bug since it's interfering with using the site?

Comment: @Troyen Good idea, retagged it.

Comment: Should this question be downvoted or un-upvoted or deleted so that it doesn't appear so highly ranked when sorting questions by votes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears this request has been honored. Enter no longer seems to submit comments on JLU.

Comment: Which browser and version are you using?  With Firefox 4.0.1 on Windows, it still submits comments.  テスト

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Any browser I tried, but only on the main site, not meta.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Indeed, Enter stopped submitting comments on the main site.  Yay!

Comment: Just for completeness sake, this was changed with proper IME handling in June 2016: [Improved IME Handling is now active](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280734/improved-ime-handling-is-now-active)

Comment: Nearly 12 years later, I am having the same exact problem with a Linux IME (fcitx/mozc). Worse yet, it seems that shift-enter doesn't do anything, so I can't even work around the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I use [this user script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2061/disable-enter-for-submitting-comments).  This at least prevents the Enter key from erroneously sending a comment when you are writing a new comment.  This is just a workaround and not a proper fix, but an incomplete workaround is better than no workaround.

*Edit*: The old version did not prevent the Enter key from sending a comment while *editing* a comment, but the new version (June 7, 2011) does.

Comment: *Zannennagara* this doesn't work on Safari (at least without more hacks). Also, virtually *every* user of this site will have this problem, so I think it should be addressed by the Stack team.

Answer (score -3):

Most IMEs allow you to rebind the commit keystroke to some other key with less side effects; you might want to consider doing so?

Comment: I do not agree that I should have to reconfigure my IME that I use everywhere on the system only because Stackexchange decides to go against the standard and act on Enter presses in textareas.

Comment: As this is the default keystroke of Microsoft and many other IME's so we really can't expect everyone to change their IME keystrokes just for the sake of this SE site.

Comment: I agree with the other commenters that it is not reasonable to ask users to change for the site. The site should be in line with the most common practise of its user base.

Comment: +1 Even if this is not a long-term solution and SE should fix it, bdonlan's workaround is helpful, so I don't understand why people down-voted this answer.

Comment: @Nicolas I did not downvote so idk but I think the people who downvoted probably interpreted this answer as that we should be expecting everybody should fix their own IME's settings instead of fixing the behavior itself, which is unrealistic in the long-term just as you pointed out.

Comment: You guys should keep in mind that the meaning of downvotes on meta is different from the main site: they do not affect anybody's reputation and are a good way to express your support for a solution or another, when addressing a technical problem. Bottom line is: don't take it personally, or as a measure of the value attached to your answer :)