# Please disable Enter to submit comments (again)

Tags: bug, status-completed

A while back we got this bug fixed:

- [Please disable Enter to submit comments](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37/please-disable-enter-to-submit-comments)

But it seems to be back.  I can't type Japanese in comments without this problem anymore.  Could you please fix it again?

Comment: It also submits for me if my screen goes black and I enter my password (pressing Enter at the end). (I'm going to submit this comment this way.)

Comment: Doesn't happen to me while typing Japanese...

Comment: @Blavius Did you type at least 15 characters?

Comment: Yes. Not that it matters now though, of course :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad. I recently deployed a rather big change in the way we handle site settings, and I broke this one along the way. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be back, at least for the past few months (as of 2021-05-20).  Running Firefox 78.10.1 esr at the moment, I've seen it on older esr versions too.

Possibly due to behavior of the IME, I often find that, as I'm typing in Japanese, hitting ENTER to confirm the conversion candidate is caught somehow by the browser instead, and my comment is committed even though I'm not done writing.  This is most annoying.  Thankfully, I can still edit my comment (since it's within the 5-minute window), but it is frustrating and a UI failure.

If we could disable ENTER from committing comments at all, that would be **most** welcome.