# Please disable enter to submit comments, yet again?

Tags: bug

Once upon a time, pressing `Enter` submitted comments, even while converting Kanji using Japanese input methods. This was fixed by disabling `Enter` to submit comments altogether:

- [Please disable Enter to submit comments](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37/please-disable-enter-to-submit-comments)  (Jun 1 '11)
- [Please disable Enter to submit comments (again)](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1599/please-disable-enter-to-submit-comments-again)  (Jun 22 '16)

Then, there was a fix. (Thank you @[Chocolate](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/users/9831/chocolate) for letting me know.)

- [Improved IME Handling, re-enabling Enter to submit](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1602/improved-ime-handling-re-enabling-enter-to-submit) (Jun 22 '16) --(*)

With this fix (*), `Enter` now sends comments, except when you're selecting the conversion suggested by the input method.

---

I feel this is irksome, and would like you to concider **disabling Enter altogether again**. 
  We press `Enter` frequently while typing in Japanese (変換文字列の確定のために): very often I  press Enter twice accidentally, which sends the comment without my intention. I usually end up editing 3-4 times before my comment is finally what I meant it to be.

`Enter` to submit suits for input boxes where it isn't otherwise pressed: comments in English, in one hand, is a good fit because no newlines are included; comments which include Japanese, on the other hand, are more like normal posts or tweets in this regard. For shortcut, `Ctrl`+`Enter` should send the comment.

The idea was briefly discussed in the [response](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1604/4223) for (*), but I don't think it gathered enough attention from the community.

Environment (just in case): Linux (Xubuntu 18.04), Mozilla Firefox 70.0.1, fcitx+mozc for Japanese input.

(Heavily rewritten 18 hours after initial post)

Comment: Related? [Improved IME Handling, re-enabling Enter to submit](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1602/9831)

Comment: I definitely also always accidentally submit comments due to this...

Comment: @Chocolate Thank you! Definitely related --- I'll update my post (heavily).